# Change job for Blue Card EU in Italy

Tags: blue-card, italy, italy-aire

I've been working under Blue Card for 22 months from 2019 to now, now I have a new contract with new company. Does anyone here knows what is the admin process for this change? I read that I need to inform to authority for the permission, but which authority, it's INPS?